# Error: No node found for selector: #email

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://discord.com/register');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'b.png'});
  await page.click('#email');
  await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('EMAIL');
  //await page.type('#email', 'World', {delay: 100});
  //await page.type('#username', 'World', {delay: 100});
  //await page.type('#password', 'World', {delay: 100});
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

this is on the https://discord.com/register page. The name of the field is clearly named "email" but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#email` selects an element with `id="email"`. Here's the Email input:

```
<input class="inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" aria-label="Email" maxlength="999" value="">
```

There's no ID attribute there, you want `name="email"`. Use

```
page.click("[name='email']")
```